# microcontroller memory calculation [Samples needed]

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, texas-instruments, flash-memory

I'm interfacing a micro-controller with the following devices:

Temperature sensor  14-bit
Magnometer + Accelometre    14-bit
Pressure sensor 24-bit
RTC Below

And a time stamp which consists of day/month/year hour/minute/second they are all in different registers  (8-bit) from RTC chip (RV-8803-C7) so I'm assuming that the total resolution to save this is then 6 byte.

Is this assumption correct?

My main question is that I have a flash memory with size of 64 Mbit (AT45DB641E).
How many samples of these sensors can I store on this memory?

I'm calculating like this (64*10^6)/(14+14+24+6*8)= 640k samples

Is this a correct assumption that I can save so many samples in the memory?

Comment: A 64Mbit memory will have size 64*1024^2 (near 5% larger than your calculation).  Moreover, just because the RTC encodes time/date in that manner there is no reason to store it that way.  You could convert it or a `time_t` value using `mktime()` for example which might be smaller and would be easier to use with the standard library time functions.

Comment: Great! thanks for the answer

Comment: It was a comment, not an answer. It remains a somewhat simplistic approach.  What about word alignment or validation?  Security from power failure during write?  And do you really need 14 or 24 bits of precision?  The least significant bits are likely to be 'noisy' in any case.

Comment: The best way to do this is to create a struct in your cross-compiler, fiddle around with the various data fields and see how much memory you end up with per struct. Optimize it for ideal size and alignment. When you have a struct you are happy with, it is all simple math from there.